# Copy and paste different ranges of numbers from one worksheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I want Excel to copy data from my first worksheet(Job!) to another one(Einfügen!) but the problem is that both  of my worksheets have lots of discontinuities. e.g like:
[image: Sample data]

In each AV, AF, AN,.. which are extracted from network analyzer there are 1600 columns but they started randomly from column 11 or any other column.

In the other worksheet(Einfügen!) I want to paste it automatically this data
which is like this:

[image]

For Example I want to copy all the data in AV from Job! to Eingabe a(`C11:F1611`) in the Einfügen! and AF from Job! to Eingabe a(`U11:Z1611`) in the Einfügen! and so on but the position of AV and other things in Job! changes when I apply new documents, so how can I have a program that copy and paste this data based on the text like: AV or AN or anything else which is written in my Job!

I am new with VBA in excel but I tried like this but since the position of data in Job! changes, it is not working.'In this example I am Copying the Data from Sheet1 (Source) to Sheet2 (Destination)

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()
    'Copy the data
Sheets("Job").Activate
Sheets("Job").Range(Range("C17659"), Range("F19259")).Copy
'Activate the destination worksheet
Sheets("Einfügen").Activate
'Select the target range
Range(Range("C11"), Range("F1611")).Select
'Paste in the target destination
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
'Copy the data
Sheets("Job").Activate
Sheets("Job").Range(Range("C9639"), Range("H11239")).Copy
'Activate the destination worksheet
Sheets("Einfügen").Activate
'Select the target range
Range(Range("C11"), Range("L1611")).Select
'Paste in the target destination
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
'Copy the data
Sheets("Job").Activate
Sheets("Job").Range(Range("C6431"), Range("H8031")).Copy
'Activate the destination worksheet
Sheets("Einfügen").Activate
'Select the target range
Range(Range("U11"), Range("Z1611")).Select
'Paste in the target destination
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
'Copy the data
Sheets("Job").Activate
Sheets("Job").Range(Range("C12847"), Range("F14447")).Copy
'Activate the destination worksheet
Sheets("Einfügen").Activate
'Select the target range
Range(Range("Q11"), Range("T1611")).Select
'Paste in the target destination
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
'Copy the data
Sheets("Job").Activate
Sheets("Job").Range(Range("C20867"), Range("F22467")).Copy
'Activate the destination worksheet
Sheets("Einfügen").Activate
'Select the target range
Range(Range("AA11"), Range("AD1611")).Select
'Paste in the target destination
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
'Copy the data
Sheets("Job").Activate
Sheets("Job").Range(Range("C28887"), Range("F30487")).Copy
'Activate the destination worksheet
Sheets("Einfügen").Activate
'Select the target range
Range(Range("M11"), Range("P1611")).Select
'Paste in the target destination
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: please edit your post and make your code readable, it's impossible to understand what goes where ??

Comment: you may want to add some more info about the data structure in sheet "Job": 1) is "AV" a text to be found in column "A"? are "AV", "AF", "AN", ... ranges always 180 columns x 3 rows (or the opposite, or what)?

Comment: inside AV and others are different frequencies and they are all numbers, and the ranege of them are 1600 columns and different amounts of rows for instanse AV has 4 rows and 1600 columns, AN has got same column but 6 rows

Answer (score 0):

Ela, you can find a good starting point in this article here:

http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/range-object.html

Essentially you need to define the range to copy from and to, then copy paste, here is an untested example:

```
Sub CopyPaste()
Dim rngCopy As Range, rngPaste As Range

Set rngCopy = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a1")
Set rngPaste = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("a1")
rngCopy.Copy rngPaste

End Sub
```

If the ranges move (which i think you are trying to say), research the dlookup function and range.end(xlup)

Sorry i can't help with your particular example- didnt understand it too well

Answer (score 0):

If the areas that you want to copy contain only numbers, then you can try this :
In the Job sheet go to HOME >> Find & Select >> Go To Special and select Constants >> Numbers >> OK.

[image]
<sub>(source: [officetuts.net](http://excel.officetuts.net/images/2014-12-29/go-to-special.png))</sub>

If the selected areas are **only** the areas that you want to copy, then you can try this macro:

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()
    Dim rngFrom As Range, rngTo As Range, rngNumbers As Range

    Set rngTo = Sheets("Einfügen").Range("C11")

    Set rngNumbers = Sheets("Job").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)

    For Each rngFrom In rngNumbers.Areas

        rngFrom.Copy
        rngTo.PasteSpecial

        Set rngTo = rngTo.Offset(rngFrom.Columns.Count)
    Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End
```

Comment: actually I have some sides rows and columns which contains numbers like product number and so on but I dont want to use those. I want to sort the data in Job worksheet based on abbreviations(AV,AF,AN,...) which I gave in columns before starting each data, since the position of these abreviation changes in every messuring and I dont want to looking for them and copy paste it, I need to make it automatic. So I thought that it might be good if first of all find these abreviation and then sorting them and then copy/paste each to the right place in the other work sheet("Einfügen").

Comment: my Job work sheet is like this I have 1600 columns and diffrent rows(4 or 6) that I need to copy , and the abreviation is in the begining of each.http://imgur.com/q6vshEY

Comment: and I dont want Hz as well, I want only copy and paste from DA1-1 to DA4-4 for each abreviation and copy-paste it , for instance I want the numbers in AV from "Job" to Eingabe a(C11:F1611) in worksheet "Einfügen"